# Correct syntax for matching a string inside a variable against an array

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a variable, `$var`, that contains a string of characters, this is a dynamic variable that contains the values from inputs.

`$var` could be `'abc'`, or `$var` could be `'blu'`,

I want to match the string inside variable against an array, and return all the matches.

```
$array = array("blue", "red", "green");
```

What is the correct syntax for writing the code in php, my rough code is below

```
$match = preg_grep($var, $array); (incorrect syntax of course)
```

I tried to put quotes and escape slashes, but so far no luck.  Any suggestion?

TIA

Comment: so, you want exact matches or a partial one? Why not to give an working example of input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$var = 're';

$array = array("blue", "red", "green");

$pattern = '/'.$var.'/';

$matches = preg_grep($pattern, $array);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($matches);
echo '<pre>';
```

returns

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "red"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "green"
}
```

Comment: and thanks for the <pre> tags example, I have been using print_r for debug and have been wondering how the online examples for arrays are well formatted.

Comment: re. <pre> tags... the second should have been </pre> :-( <blush>

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$match = preg_grep('/' . $var . '/', $array);
```

[Patterns for PCREs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) must be enclosed in [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Of course you have to adjust the pattern, depending on your needs. E.g. if  you want to match all strings in the array that **start** with the string in `$var` you have to change it to:

```
$match = preg_grep('/^' . $var . '/', $array);
```

And so on...